# Can spring MVC parse JSON into @RequestParams

Tags: json, spring-mvc

Is it possible to use the annotation `@RequestParam` to parse json formatted data from a request just like it is possible to parse `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded data?

I.e. if my request body is:

```
{ firstName : "John", lastName : "Doe" }
```

I would like to be able to have a method looking like

```
public void savePerson(@RequestParam String firstName, @RequestParam lastName) {
    // handle data
}
```

Where the value of `firstName` is "John" and the value of `lastName` is "Doe". I have tried to make this work but it only works for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded data. When sending json formatted data I get a `400` response saying that the paramaters are missing.

I am using Spring 3.2.0 and the `Content-Type`header of my requests have been matching the data format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.
Change to this

```
public void savePerson(@RequestBody Person) {
```

and this

```
{"person" : { "firstName" : "John", "lastName" : "Doe" }
```

Comment: That is possible but now the method is bound to this format. It can no longer accept data formatted in any other way right? Can i send application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoded data that is understood by this method?

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson They are get or post requests ? Have you used the new spring 3.2 testing features - they are really useful for issues like it.

Comment: I have been trying POST and PUT. Would it matter which method is used? I'll check out the testing features as well.

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson yes it definitely matters

Comment: @NimChimpsky - what Spring 3.2 testing features are you referring to?  I am having the same question - can you please elaborate?

Comment: @EricB. the first link if you google "spring 3.2 test" http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html

Comment: I think you should wrote an explanation of why is not possible. In some situations it is not possible to use the @requestbody annotation.